# Python: get all the possible combinations for allocating x apples to y baskets subject to constraint

Tags: python, numpy, combinations, permutation

Suppose we have `x` apples and `y` baskets, we want to allocate all the apples to baskets such that each basket at most get `z` apples. How to write Python codes to get all possible combinations.
For small number of `y`, I can just loop with respect to `y` as follows (x=5, y=3, z=2).

```
all_chances = np.zeros((0,3))
for a in range(3):
   for b in range(3):
      for c in range(3):
          if a+b+c == 5:
             all_chances = np.vstack((all_chances, np.array([a,b,c])))
```

Basically, `all_chances` are

```
array([[1., 2., 2.],
   [2., 1., 2.],
   [2., 2., 1.]])
```

My question is: what if y is a large number, like x = 30, y = 26, z=2? Do I need to loop 26 times?

Comment: Yes, given that algorithm for generating the combinations, you would have to nest 26 loops, one per basket.  Obviously, that approach is not particularly viable.  Instead, try setting up an array of `y` baskets.  Loop across the array of baskets, instead of nesting one loop per basket.

Comment: Two suggestions: (1) use some form of recursion (2) use Young diagrams

Answer (score 0):

I messed around with your question...  tried implementing a sort of tree-based approach bc I thought it'd be clever, but my laptop chokes on it.  I was curious how many permutations we're looking for with these large numbers anyway, and changed the problem (for myself) to simply counting the permutations to see if it was even doable on a light-weight laptop.

I get 154,135,675,070 unique permutations.

To get started...  I messed around with itertools, and permutations took forever with lists of length 26.  So...  to remind myself of the long-forgotten formula to at least count distinct permutations, I found this...  https://socratic.org/questions/how-many-distinct-permutations-can-be-made-from-the-letters-of-the-word-infinity

With that I ran the following to get a count.  It runs in under a second.

```
from numpy import prod
from math import factorial
import itertools

# number of unique permutations
def count_distinct_permutations(tup):
    value_counts = [len(list(grp)) for _, grp in itertools.groupby(tup)]
    return factorial(sum(value_counts)) / prod([float(factorial(x)) for x in value_counts])

# starting values
x = 30 # apples
y = 26 # baskets
z = 3  # max per basket

# count possible results
result = 0
for combos in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(z), y):
    if sum(combos) == x:
        result += count_distinct_permutations(combos)
```

Now...  this obviously does NOT answer your specific question.  Honestly I couldn't hold the result you're looking for in memory anyway.  But...  you can make some inferences with this...  with your chosen values, there's only 12 combinations of values, but between 15k and 50 million permutations of each combination.

You could look at each combination...  in the `count_distinct_permutations()` function, `itertools.groupby` feeds you how many of each number from `(0,1,2)` is in the combination, and you could work with each of those twelve results to infer some stuff.  Not sure what, but I also am not quite sure what to do with 154 billion lists of length 26.  :)

Hope there was something useful here, even if it didn't answer your exact question.  Good luck!

Comment: I'm getting the same number `154,135,675,070` of partitions using I think a rather different method. So that's reassuring..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method based on Young diagrams. For example, 4 baskets, 6 eggs, max 3 eggs per basket. If we order the baskets by how full they are we get Young diagrams.

```
x x x x   x x x x   x x x     x x x      x x
x x       x         x x x     x x        x x
          x                   x          x x
```

The code below enumerates all possible Young diagrams and for each enumerates all possible permutations.

The same logic can also be used to count.

```
from itertools import product, combinations
from functools import lru_cache
import numpy as np

def enum_ord_part(h, w, n, o=0):
    if h == 1:
        d = n
        for idx in combinations(range(w), d):
            idx = np.array(idx, int)
            out = np.full(w, o)
            out[idx] = o+1
            yield out
    else:
        for d in range((n-1)//h+1, min(w, n) + 1):
            for idx, higher in product(combinations(range(w), d),
                                       enum_ord_part(h-1, d, n-d, o+1)):
                idx = np.array(idx)
                out = np.full(w, o)
                out[idx] = higher
                yield out

def bc(n, k):
    if 2*k > n:
        k = n-k
    return np.prod(np.arange(n-k+1, n+1, dtype='O')) // np.prod(np.arange(1, k+1, dtype='O'))

@lru_cache(None)
def count_ord_part(h, w, n):
    if h == 1:
        return bc(w, n)
    else:
        return sum(bc(w, d) * count_ord_part(h-1, d, n-d)
                   for d in range((n-1)//h+1, min(w, n) + 1))
```

Few examples:

```
>>> for i, l in enumerate(enum_ord_part(3, 4, 6), 1):
...     print(l, end=' ' if i % 8 else '\n')
... 
[3 3 0 0] [3 0 3 0] [3 0 0 3] [0 3 3 0] [0 3 0 3] [0 0 3 3] [3 2 1 0] [2 3 1 0]
[3 1 2 0] [2 1 3 0] [1 3 2 0] [1 2 3 0] [2 2 2 0] [3 2 0 1] [2 3 0 1] [3 1 0 2]
[2 1 0 3] [1 3 0 2] [1 2 0 3] [2 2 0 2] [3 0 2 1] [2 0 3 1] [3 0 1 2] [2 0 1 3]
[1 0 3 2] [1 0 2 3] [2 0 2 2] [0 3 2 1] [0 2 3 1] [0 3 1 2] [0 2 1 3] [0 1 3 2]
[0 1 2 3] [0 2 2 2] [3 1 1 1] [1 3 1 1] [1 1 3 1] [1 1 1 3] [2 2 1 1] [2 1 2 1]
[2 1 1 2] [1 2 2 1] [1 2 1 2] [1 1 2 2]
>>> 
>>> print(f'{count_ord_part(2, 26, 30):,}')
154,135,675,070
>>> print(f'{count_ord_part(50, 30, 1000):,}')
63,731,848,167,716,295,344,627,252,024,129,873,636,437,590,711
```